# Enlarge Exchange volume

Tags: hyper-v, exchange, storage, vhd

I would like to enlarge an Exchange volume.

Normally i would

- shut down the vm, because its an VHD, not an VHDX,
- enlarge with Hyper-V Manager,
- start up and
- extend given partition with diskmgmt.msc at runtime.

Now I have found several articles that tell me to move the mailbox to another server beforehand. However, the Exchange is a stand-alone installation running on-premise. So a target to move is not given at all.

The only thing I could think of was to "Disable" certain Exchange services, restart, change the disk, then restore the services to their original state and have the server restart.

Maybe the extension of the partition does not require to stop Exchange at all?

Any help is welcome.

Kind regards,

Udo

Comment: Your steps are fine when you only have one exchange server. If you had a shared dag or multiple mailbox servers, you would want to do a switchover to keep the database available while you configure the others. I'd recommend migrating the DB to a VHDX while you're at it, so that you can extend it without needing to restart in the future

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you made the same post on another forum, and there are a lot of experts who give you similar advice. In my opinion, in addition to their recommendations, you can also back up your Exchange server in case something unexpected happens.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).